# How do I avoid triggering the base alarm?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution, the-missing-link

In my first playthrough, I was able to get out of the ship without setting off the alarm.  In my second playthrough, despite knocking out every guard and never triggering an alarm, when I passed the security checkpoint I was notified that the base was put on an heightened alert state due to some alarms from the ship.  What did I do differently?  The only thing I remember is a turret seeing me for a few seconds.

Comment: IIRC, _any_ turret sightings count as an alarm, even if it doesn't set off the rest of the guards.

Comment: @JeffMercado hmm... the weird thing is I got ghost and smooth operator on all the missions

Comment: Funny, when I reached the first mission with the turret, I remember not getting  those bonuses because I tried to be cute and just jump past the hall. Fortunately I saved beforehand and reloaded and dispatched of the turret and got those bonuses. It might have changed since then with all the patches.

Comment: Also, if a turret or camera spots a dead/unconscious body, it will usually trigger and alarm.

Comment: Yesterday I tried the Factory Zero achievement and though I failed (whyever?) the base wasn't alarmed. Now I entered it and saw the huge amount of soldiers and the robot that was never active during my first playthrough... i am so annoyed by this and have to go back a few savegames to try out where I failed... did you actually find out, what you did wrong?

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic no, I have no clue either.  I'm absolutely positive I knocked out everyone without causing a single alarm.

Comment: I tried another run but the Steam servers are currently down for an hour and I don't want to risk ruining everything by unsynced achievements. I hope they'll soon come back online so I can try to finish this and see whether it's a bug or not because I have only picked up Secs for the codes and the quest items therefore everything should be fine for now.

Answer (score 3):

Being spotted by a turret will immediately alert it, but as long as it doesn't shoot at you and alert guards, who then trigger alarm panels, it doesn't affect whether or not you get the Smooth Operator bonus.

Your problem, however, might be that some guard that you missed was patrolling and stumbled upon one of your victims. Depending on where you are in the game, *you can also trigger guards or robots to spawn*, and if one of these are in the vicinity of your handiwork, they can be alerted. A camera can also pick up dead or knocked out bodies, and if it goes past "Suspicious", it will cause an alarm.

> How do I avoid triggering the base alarm?

The answer to this question is simply: avoid being spotted by guards or cameras and prevent them from seeing dead or knocked out bodies.

> What did I do differently?

This question calls for speculation and can't really be answered with the information you have given.